# Can I use !# Rscripts in Windows

Tags: r, rscript

In linux I used to put `!#/usr/bin/Rscript` so I can call `myScript.R [options]` on windows replacing the /usr path by the correct path C:/Program... does not work (nothing is happening). The only way I know is to do `Rscript.exe myScript.R [options]`.
Is it possible to mimic the Unix behaviour ?

Comment: cygwin gives you bash (but it is not a lightweight install).  Native windows, you can use a shortcut.

Comment: There is also MSys which is more lightweight than Cygwin -- Windows is (on purpose, I may add) not like Unix, so you cannot just expect this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the default `cmd.exe` shell on Windows and are willing to use a second file then you can create a batch file, `myScript.bat`, containing this line:

```
Rscript.exe myScript.R %*
```

and then run it like this:

```
myScript
```

You can include arguments at the end of this line but they should not include embedded spaces.

Comment: Ok thanks all for contributions, @G. Grothendieck what do you mean by embedded spaces ?

Comment: If you do this `myScript "a b"` then `a` and `b` will be passed as separate arguments rather than a single argument with an embedded space.

Answer (score 1):

Grothendieck is right. I'll show another idea to mix the two files.

```
rem <- function(...) invisible(T)
rem( '
Rscript.exe %~F0
EXIT /B
rem ')
### above=BAT, below=R

cat('Hello, World', file='hello.txt')
```

Save this as "hello.bat" and execute it. You can find more details in [my blog](http://tomizonor.wordpress.com/2013/04/20/single-script-windows/).